# Whole genome amino acid composition tool?

Tags: bacteriology, amino-acids, genomes, codon-usage

I'm interested in a statistical tool to get bacterial codon usage at genomic level. Ideally, the tool should be flexible to analyse hundreds of bacterial genomes.

I've looked in MeSH terms database but I'm a bit lost [when I search for "Genetic Code" and Software](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=%28%22Genetic%20Code%22%5BMesh%5D%29%20AND%20%22Software%22%5BMesh%5D).

I'm looking for an output like this one:

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Please clarify a little. What is "genetic code usage"? Do you mean the code that a species uses or are you thinking of [codon biases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codon_usage_bias)? What are you trying to do with MESH? How do you get aa composition at the genome level? You mean the usage ratio of aas in the whole proteome? Please [edit] your post and include the actual scientific question you are trying to answer.

Comment: Just to amplify the comment from  @terdon - do you mean the amino acid composition of the proteome (i.e. taking into account protein abundance) or do you mean that simply calculated from the translation of all open reading frames?

Comment: In response to the comments, I edited my question and added my ideal output.

Comment: check [this](http://www.kazusa.or.jp/codon/).
You can get the tables for multiple genomes and then apply your statistics. You can use a script to automate the download

Comment: You should also be aware that within subsets of the genome, there are different codon biases. For example, metabolic genes use a different codon bias than whole-genome transcript bias. Also, mitochondrial DNA has a different codon bias from genomic DNA codon bias.

Comment: @Masi could you clarify _how_ you would like the answer to be improved? Perhaps edit the question to define a specific statistical calculation you would like to see?

Comment: More practical examples and more comparison to other existing tools. I have seen some in different laboratories and would like to have different views why to use some tools. This is a huge topic and I cannot see that my answer can answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

I have written a [script](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14062712/ensembl_get_codon_count.pl) that will get you started. It downloads all protein coding transcripts of the species of interest from Ensembl and prints the codon use for each codon on each transcript.

You will need to install the `Bio::EnsEMBL::Registry` Perl module, see [here](http://www.ensembl.org/info/docs/api/api_installation.html) for instructions. The script also uses the [`Math::Round`](http://search.cpan.org/~grommel/Math-Round-0.06/Round.pm) module, everything else should be installed by default with your Perl distribution. Finally, the script expects to be run from a Unix/Linux operating system.

#### Example run

```
 ensembl_get_codon_count.pl human > human.csv
```

#### Example output

```
Gene Name   Gene ID      Transcript ID  Ala_GCC Ala_GCC_% Ala_GCA Ala_GCA_% Ala_GCG Ala_GCG_% Ala_GCT Ala_GCT_%
CRLF2   ENSG00000205755 ENST00000400841    6       40        6      40         0       0         3       20
```

In the example above, the transcript ENST00000400841 of the human CRLF2 gene, contains a total of 15 Alanine residues, 6 of which are coded for by the GCC codon (40%), 6 by the GCA codon (40%) and 3 by the GCT codon (20%). The GCG codon is not used (0%).

This is a cut version of the output, the actual output lines are much longer since they include all codons and there will be one line per protein coding transcript.

This script should at least get you started since it will provide you with the raw data needed to perform your statistical analyses. If you use it in published work, I would appreciate it if you could let me know (my email is included in the script) and perhaps mention me in the acknowledgements :).